# Pointwise Convergence Implies Uniform?

Tags: analysis

Let $f_{n} \to 0$ pointwise on the interval $[-A,A]$ where $f_{n}$ are continuous and uniformly bounded. Can we show the convergence is uniform?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: Indeed the 'best' similar result in some sense is the [Arzela-Ascoli Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzela-Ascoli_theorem), which you might be interested to learn.

Comment: This can't *not* be a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Choose two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ of real numbers so that $0<a_n<b_n<1$ for each $n$ and  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n=1$. For each $n$, let $f_n$ be the function on $[0,1]$ whose graph consists of the straight line segments from $(0,0)$ to $(a_n,0)$,  from $(a_n,0)$ to $(b_n,1)$, and from $(b_n,1)$ to $(1,0)$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence. We have, however, [Egorov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem), which for the given example states:

Suppose that $f_n$ are measurable and converges almost everywhere to some function $f$ on $[-A,A]$. For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a measurable set $B_\epsilon\subset [-A,A]$ with measure (total length) $\mu(B_\epsilon) < \epsilon$, such that the convergence is uniform on $[-A,A] \setminus B_\epsilon$.